# install PARADOX extension for PHP

Tags: php, paradox

I have an ApacheFriends XAMPP running on my windows machine and i am trying to access some Paradox database files directly from PHP.

I see that there is an extension for this but how can i install it for my windows system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- copy the extension's .dll to `path\to\xampp\php\ext\`
- and a line similar to `extension=php_paradox.dll` in `path\to\xampp\php\php.ini`, where php_paradox.dll is the name of your extension's .dll file
- configure your extension's parameters in `path\to\xampp\php\php.ini`, if any, per your extension's intructions
- restart Apache

If you have pecl installed, `pecl install paradox` might fetch it on to your system. If not you must step though [the ugly steps of extension compiling](http://www.php.net/manual/en/internals2.php):

- download php source code
- copy the extension's source in `path/php-src/ext/` dir
- `./configure --prefix=/where/to/install/php --enable-debug --enable-maintainer-zts --enable-cgi --enable-cli --with-mysql=/path/to/mysql --with-PARADOX=shared,PATH/TO/DIR`
- make, make install and you'll find the .dll in `install/path/ext/` dir

Comment: any change on where i can get the DLL for paradox ?

Answer (score 0):

Mike,
I believe that that XAMPP install includes Paradox support by default.  Simply use px_get_record() et. al. and you should be good.